# Peculiar noise when observing a square wave

Tags: oscilloscope, wave, function-generator, square

I'm using the following function generator: http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/499058.pdf?_ga=1.129729036.1263433037.1467971694 and a Tektronix TDS 1002B scope for some measurments.
Most of the time I use the function generator's square wave output(at %50 duty-cycle) as an input to a circuit.

The issue is that I see a lightning-like random flickering noise when I observe the rising or falling edges of the squarewave above 200Hz. 
It is hard to describe what I see so I uploaded a very short record of the scope screen.
Here is how it looks like:
https://youtu.be/hOy5-SOk2mg

I would like to describe the setup briefly to elimitae some possible causes.
To observe the signal from the function generator, I first hook up the function generator's squarewave output to the scope's channel (I also use a 50ohm terminator to eliminate ringing).
Below is how the BNC is connected to 50ohm output of the function generator:

[image]

And here below is how BNC is connected to the scope channel(If I don't use 50ohm terminator I still have the noise plus ringing):

[image]

I first thought the noise could be coming from the scope itself so I hooked up the scope probe to its own builtin 1kHz output. But the edges were very clean without any weird interference.
I also tried the setup with different BNC coax cables and still having the same issue. I also don't observe this noise on the scope screen only if the function generator's output is set below 200Hz.

Do you have any idea what could be the issue here? And could it be fixed with a different setup.

**Edit**:

Below is a photo from the scope screen. I had to take tens of photos to catch when the noise hits. Below when the noise strikes:

[image]

As I wrote this happens randomly all of a sudden. So the noise is not continuously there that was the reason why I had uploaded a video.

Another clearer photo when the noise appears:

[image]

**Edit 2:**

### Some new observations:

1-) I used 2-prong power plugs and the issue still existed. So it is not related to ground loops

2-) I cannot sample fast enough 10ns signals with my DAQ device

3-) If I use 20MHz bandwidth instead of 60MHz in settings the noise becomes better

4-) Noise only exists for the square wave output not for sinusidal or triangle

> And I guess the most important observation is the following:
>
> When I set the function generator main output's Vpp anything less than
>   2V the noise disappears totally. And I hear a 'tick' sound the momemnt
>   Vpp is adjusted below 2V (a tick sound similar to when you hear in CC
>   limiting in a power supply). There is obviously some relation with
>   function generator's pulse output amplitude but have no idea what it
>   could be. But under 2Vpp if I play with duty cycle noise appears again for different duty cycles..

Comment: Some screen captures from that video would be helpful.

Comment: can you see the video?

Comment: Yes, but other people may not be able to due to firewalls at work or YouTube's country restrictions. We also want the question to remain useful if you take the video down.

Comment: it is too hard to describe this type of noise with a static photo thanks it appears and disappears

Comment: Not watching video.  Ain't gonna happen.  Post a picture or scope snapshot of what you are asking about.

Comment: Alright i will come up with photos as well. The thing is this interference like noise appears and disappears randomly. That was the reason for a video.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I just added a photo of the signal when the noise is striking.

Comment: Is there any chance you have an analog scope available? Sometimes digital scopes tell lies, and a different view may shed light on the problem. Some of the lies involve aliasing, so take Olin's questions about the scales seriously.

Comment: Wow, that is weird.  Take a proper scope shot that shows the time and voltage scales, or tell us what they are.  Also, what it the bandwidth rating of the scope?  What is it's sample rate as you have it set up?

Comment: This is 60MHz scope 1kHz signal square wave 2Vpp

Comment: @BrianDrummond If it was the scope I dont understand why this noise doesn't appear when I use the scope's builtin 1kHz pulse generator. So I thought it is not the scope.

Comment: For example : if (a) you are triggering off the falling edge and using holdoff to view the positive edge, and (b) there is the right pattern of jitter in the pulse length and (c) the scope is undersampling the data and interpolating across different cycles to draw the waveform, then one late (but clean) edge can be interpreted as a glitch instead of a late edge. I don't think that applies at 1 kHz though.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I just checked with a 10MHz old analog scope and I dont see the noise anymore. You might be right. But the thing is that unlike the digital scope, the analog scope doesn't either show the ringing effect when I unplug the 50 Ohm terminator. So Im really screwed which one to believe in :(

Comment: I'm inclined to believe an analog scope that slow may simply be hiding the problem. Mine is 400MHz... If that photo shows 10ns/division then the potential problem lies outside its bandwidth.

Comment: @user16307 It might be helpful to include a photo of one of the times, as seen in the video, where the strange signal *precedes* the intended signal.

Comment: @AndrewMorton what do u mean? My edit is showing the frozen signal is that enough?

Comment: @user16307 If the spurious signal always follows the intended signal, it could be that something about the latter causes the former. That is the only photo evidence we see at the moment. Another picture of the glitch preceding the intended signal would give a more complete story. Also, is the inside of that T-connector as dirty as the outside?

Comment: Same results without T-connector or different BNC cables.

Comment: I seem to think it might be the signal generator. Feed the 1kHz signal into a PC soundcard, record it as a .wav file, then analyze the waveform and see if the "lightning dips" appear there too. If it does, it's either the signal generator, or the cabling, or some odd ground-loop or power issue. I really doubt it is a Tek scope.

Comment: I can see why this was about to get closed before the edits. Now it turned in to a good question IMO.

Comment: Someone tell me if I'm being silly here. What does an eye diagram ([Is it possible to display an eye pattern on my oscilloscope?](http://www.tek.com/support/faqs/it-possible-display-eye-pattern-my-oscilloscope)) tell you about the signal from the frequency generator? [Eye Diagram Basics: Reading and applying eye diagrams](http://www.edn.com/design/test-and-measurement/4389368/Eye-Diagram-Basics-Reading-and-applying-eye-diagrams).

Comment: This question has been flagged for closure due to lack of information. The question is unclear, but the comment stream points to a possible solution-if the OP helps out. Voting to leave open for now.

Comment: Guessing: high frequency ringing is always there and you are seeing it only when the scope samples at the right moment.  Tek makes great scopes, but they are digital devices.  If your ringing frequency exceeds the nyquist criteria for the scope, you can have this kind of artifact when the scampes line up with the peaks of the ringing.

Comment: Should be "samples" in the last line

Comment: Please see my new edit 'Edit 2' for new observations about this issue.

Comment: @JohnBirckhead The anomaly also occurs *before* the signal transition, as seen in the video. (And I liked "scampes".)

Answer (score -1):

This would not be an answer, but reading through question and comment stream I have a suggestion: reach generator's manufacturer, and report the problem. This way they would be able to know about your issue, prove or disprove it. There're could be other people who may suffer from the same issue, everyone will thank you for reporting. Additionally, you will be able to test manufacturer's support to see and feel if you still want to use their products :)

One more quick thought: coaxial cables and probes may have attenuation switch in them, and you can change their bandwidth. Did you play with it? What I see on your "clearer photo" looks very familiar... kind of impedance mismatch with (rising or falling) edge shooting back into the wire.

Comment: You really shouldn't use answers to make comments - there is a reason for the way the reputation system is set up.

Comment: Reputation system is crap. Helping and guiding people solving their problems is the value. The question already has 26 comments to it, which means it is a time to aggregate knowledge and give conclusion or direction.